# Where do I find a sequence diagram for how maven does a build?

Tags: maven-2

I'm working on my first maven project and I've been tasked with improving build times on a very large project with lots of modules.  I've found that the Sonnatype documents / books are verbose and they seem to gloss over the basics.

What I could really use right now is a sequence diagram for how maven does a build relating how the pom.xml elements get executed during the build.

Does anyone know of a sequence diagram for how maven does basic builds and builds with more than one module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading up on the [Maven build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

[This](http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html) might be a good reference for increasing speed as well.